# How do I embed a listing in a tabular?

Tags: tables, listings

How do I embed a source code listing in a tabular without messing up the spacing?

Here's a MWE of the problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}[h]
  %\lstset{numbers=none, language={[x86masm]Assembler}, basicstyle=\linespread{0.8}\footnotesize}
  \begin{tabular}{l|p{6cm}|l}
    Fact name
    & Description
    & Assembly code example\\
    \hline
    hello & Instruction  in  allocates  bytes of memory for the object blah blah blah.
    &
\begin{lstlisting}
push 28h
call operator new
\end{lstlisting}%
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Attempt one.}
\end{table*}
\begin{table*}[h]
  %\lstset{numbers=none, language={[x86masm]Assembler}, basicstyle=\linespread{0.8}\footnotesize}
  \begin{tabular}{l|p{6cm}|p{6cm}}
    Fact name
    & Description
    & Assembly code example\\
    \hline
    hello & Instruction  in  allocates  bytes of memory for the object blah blah blah.
    &
\begin{lstlisting}
push 28h
call operator new
\end{lstlisting}\\%
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Attempt two.}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

[image: Rendered MWE]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can define a `\lstnewenvironment` with the adjustments for the specific case.

The option here in `\lstset` can also be given as options to `tabularlstlisting` or changed locally with

```
\begin{tabularlstlisting}[<options>]
```

Full example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstnewenvironment{tabularlstlisting}[1][]
 {%
  \lstset{aboveskip=-1.3ex,belowskip=-3.5ex,#1}%
 }
 {}

\begin{document}

\lstset{numbers=none, language={[x86masm]Assembler}, basicstyle=\linespread{0.8}\footnotesize}

\begin{tabular}{l|p{6cm}|p{4cm}}
Fact name
 & Description
 & Assembly code example\\
\hline
hello & Instruction  in  allocates  bytes of memory for the object blah blah blah. &
\begin{tabularlstlisting}
push 28h
call operator new
\end{tabularlstlisting}
\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{l|p{6cm}|p{4cm}}
Fact name
 & Description
 & Assembly code example\\
\hline
hello & Instruction  in  allocates  bytes of memory for the object blah blah blah. &
\begin{tabularlstlisting}
push 28h
call operator new
push 28h
call operator new
push 28h
call operator new
push 28h
call operator new
\end{tabularlstlisting}
\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can use a `\vskip` to adjust placement. I found that `\baselineskip+\smallskipamount` gave ok result. As demonstrated by the added rule to visualize things.

```
\documentclass{article}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}[h]
  \lstset{numbers=none, language={[x86masm]Assembler},
    basicstyle=%\linespread{0.8}
               %\footnotesize
  }
  \begin{tabular}{l|p{6cm}|p{6cm}}
    Fact name
    & Description
    & Assembly code example\\
    \hline
    hello & Instruction\rlap{\rule{10cm}{0.4pt}}  in  allocates  bytes of memory for the object blah blah blah.
    &
\vskip-\baselineskip
\vskip-\smallskipamount
\begin{lstlisting}
push 28h
call operator new
\end{lstlisting}
\kern-\baselineskip
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Attempt two.}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A solution with a `\raisebox`  of the relevant value (the default value of the `aboveskip` key is `\medskipamount`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}[!h]\setlength{\extrarowheight}{3pt}
  %\lstset{numbers=none, language={[x86masm]Assembler}, basicstyle=\linespread{0.8}\footnotesize}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
\centering
  \begin{tabular}{l|p{6cm}|>{\vspace*{-\dimexpr \baselineskip+0.55ex}\arraybackslash}l}
    Fact name
    & Description
    & Assembly code example\\[1ex]
    \hline
    hello & Instruction in allocates bytes of memory for the object blah blah blah.
    &
\raisebox{-\medskipamount}{
\hspace{-1em}\begin{lstlisting}^^J
push 28h^^J
call operator new
\end{lstlisting}}\\%
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Attempt two.}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you do not need syntax highlighting then use package `fancyvrb`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{SaveVerbatim}[gobble=0]{VerbEnv}
push 28h
call operator new
\end{SaveVerbatim}

\caption{Attempt two.}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{l|X|l}
Fact name & Description & Assembly code example\\[1ex]\hline
hello & Instruction in allocates bytes of memory for the object blah blah blah.
      & \BUseVerbatim[baseline=t]{VerbEnv}
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could also use a `tikz matrix`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{table*}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix[matrix of nodes,
        column sep=0pt, row sep=0pt,
        column 1/.style={nodes={text width=2cm}},
        column 2/.style={nodes={text width=4.5cm}},
        column 3/.style={nodes={text width=4.5cm}},
        row 1/.style={nodes={minimum height=1ex, 
            text height=1.5ex,text depth=.25ex}},
        row 2/.style={nodes={minimum height=11ex, anchor=center}},
        ] (m) {%
            Fact name
            & Description
            & Assembly code example\\
            hello & Instruction  in  allocates  bytes of memory for the object blah blah blah.
            &
            % leave the code without space before
            \begin{lstlisting}
push 28h
call operator new
            \end{lstlisting}
            \\
        };
        \draw[thick] (m-1-1.south west) -- (m-1-3.south east); 
        \draw[thick] (m-1-1.north east) -- (m-2-1.south east);
        \draw[thick] (m-1-2.north east) -- (m-2-2.south east);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Attempt one.}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

[image]